# How can I make a div slide offscreen, and have another div expand to fill the space?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm currently messing with an information column on the left side of the screen. What I would like is for the column to smoothly slide off the left edge of the screen, and for the remaining content to smoothly fill up the space. I can use `transform: translateX(-100%);` to make the column slide off the screen, but the content in the center of the page stays where it is and doesn't fill the space.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .left-column {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 16.67%;
  }

  .left-column.collapsed {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  .center-content {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function toggleLeftColumn() {
    var leftCol = document.getElementById("leftCol");
    leftCol.classList.toggle("collapsed");
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-column" id="leftCol">
      Left column content
    </div>

    <div class="center-content">
      Center content
      <button onclick="toggleLeftColumn()">Toggle left column</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I get the center content to fill the empty space as the left column slides offscreen?

EDIT: added a proper reproducible example.

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet so we can see your HTML structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're still missing an [mre] -- your code is not actually displaying in flex format. Please add your real code to the question so it can be answered reliably.

Comment: @AHaworth sorry about that. I've added a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with transform is that the space initially occupied by the element remains, so other elements aren't affected.

You could just move the lefthand element by a negative margin-left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .left-column {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 16.67%;
  }
  
  .left-column.collapsed {
    margin-left: -16.67%;
  }
  
  .center-content {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function toggleLeftColumn() {
    var leftCol = document.getElementById("leftCol");
    leftCol.classList.toggle("collapsed");
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-column" id="leftCol">
      Left column content
    </div>

    <div class="center-content">
      Center content
      <button onclick="toggleLeftColumn()">Toggle left column</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With just flexbox this is not easy. You can't have a good fly-in/fly-out effect.

I solved it by a slightly different approach:

- added an extra content element inside the left pane (that one will *fly*)

  - this is important as we will keep this element at its original size to prevent the visible collapse and text reflow
- got rid of the `translate` - it just complicates things
- made the left pane container `position: relative`
- made the left pane content element `position: absolute` and `right:0`

  - `right: 0` makes sure the flyout effect works (otherwise the element may overlap the main content element which is undesirable)
- used fixed widths (you cold use screen percentages instead of pixel values, though, **important is to have some values to animate from and to**)
- animate all aspects of the `flex` rule

**Note:**

The javascript part is just for the sake of the demonstration, but you can use it to trigger the change.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (document.querySelector('.left-column').classList.contains('collapsed')) {
    document.querySelector('.left-column').classList.remove('collapsed');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.left-column').classList.add('collapsed');
  }
})
```

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-column {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  transition: flex .5s;
}

.left-column-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0000;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.center-content {
  1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.collapsed {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  transition: flex: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="left-column-content">
      Left column content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center-content">
    Center content
  </div>
</div>

<button>collapse</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is no display for the container of these two elements, although I think I've solved this sliding problem using the height property, by setting it to 0px at (.collapsed) class and it transitioned it into .left-column class, It worked :)

```js
let collapsed = false

function collapse(){
    collapsed = !collapsed
    document.querySelector(".left-column").classList.toggle("collapsed", collapsed)
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = collapse
```

```css
.left-column {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 16.67%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.left-column.collapsed {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    height:0px;
}

.center-content {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column">
    Left column content
</div>

<div class="center-content">
    Center content
</div>

<button>collapse</button>
```